# Avoiding crossing lines in DFD diagrams

Tags: data-flow-diagram

I have researched DFDs reasonably extensively, and received some feedback from peers about my first DFD. I have since reworked it to avoid lines crossing by duplicating the 'Pokemon' data store.

I have read that it should read left to right. Does this mean I should create another 'Pokemon Trainer' entity on the right, or is this not needed?

**Scenario:**
Users (Pokemon Trainers) sign up for an account. They can search for Pokemon from a database. They can 'catch' Pokemon which are then stored in their own Pokedex. Users can view their caught Pokemon, along with information about that Pokemon.

First DFD
[image]

Second DFD[image: Pokemon DFD]

Comment: Pokémon Trainer looks like it could benefit from being at the topmost of the diagram as it looks to be the superset action.